# R Markdown incorrect labelling in Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMyOM.png)

```
purple <- birth_data %>% filter(state_color =='purple' ) %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(mean_age = mean(mother_age)) 
red <- birth_data %>% filter(state_color =='red' ) %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(mean_age = mean(mother_age)) 
blue <- blue %>% mutate(state_color = 'blue')
purple <- purple %>% mutate(state_color  = 'purple')
red <- red %>% mutate(state_color = 'red')



graph <- ggplot() +  geom_line(data = blue, aes(x = year, y = mean_age, color = "Blue"), size =1.5)+
  geom_line(data = purple, aes(x = year, y = mean_age, color = "Purple"), size = 1.5)+
  geom_line(data = red, aes(x = year, y = mean_age, color = "Red"), size = 1.5) + labs(color='state_color')

graph
```

I am trying to set the state_color to the same color as the name so blue should be blue in the legend. Unfortunately, it's not working?

---

Also, this isn't the main point of the question but is there a more efficient way of doing this problem instead of separating them out and then fusing them back together?

Comment: Try with `scale_color_manual(values = c("Blue" = "blue", "Red" = "red", ...)`.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand how `{ggplot}` controls the colours and in particular what `aesthetic mappings` are and what `parameters` are.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
         , state_colour = c("red","red", "blue","blue", "purple","purple"))

df
  x y state_colour
1 1 1          red
2 2 1          red
3 3 2         blue
4 4 2         blue
5 5 3       purple
6 6 3       purple
```

use a standard ggplot call:

```
ggplot(data = df) + 
   geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = state_colour))
```

you get:

[image]

Why is that? You are assigning the color aesthetics in to a variable that is a character vector/factor with distinct values. The "word" as such has no meaning. You could have used A, B, C. `{ggplot}` uses its - admittedly ugly - default colour sequence.

If you want to subset your data frame as you did, you can assign a color to this layer (i.e. outside the `aes()`)

```
ggplot() + 
   geom_line(data = df %>% filter(state_colour == "blue")
            , aes(x = x, y = y)
            , colour = "blue"    # colour is now a paramter and not an aesthetic mapping!
)
```

This yields:

[image: setting colour parameter]